# PayPal Orders v2 create response: The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation

Tags: dart, paypal

I am trying to create an order for a payment with dart and PayPal API Orders V2

This is the request I do at the url `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders`

The headers are correct. This is the body:

```
{
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "EUR",
        "value": "5.0"
      },
      "items": [{
        "name": "First time",
        "unit_amount": {
          "currency_code": "EUR",
          "value": "2.0"
        },
        "quantity": "1"
      },
        {
          "name": "Second item",
          "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "value": "3.0"
          },
          "quantity": "1"
        }]
    }
  ]
}
```

I get this error:

> The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect,
> or failed business validation

If I remove the `items` array from the body the request works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing items, your amount needs a `breakdown` object, as documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-amount_with_breakdown

An example:

```
                "purchase_units": [{
                    "description": "Stuff",
                    "amount": {
                        "value": "20.00",
                        "currency_code": "USD",
                        "breakdown": {
                            "item_total": {
                                "currency_code": "USD",
                                "value": "20.00"
                            },
                        }
                    },
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "unit_amount": {
                                "currency_code": "USD",
                                "value": "10.00"
                            },
                            "quantity": "1",
                            "name": "Item 1",
                        },
                        {
                            "unit_amount": {
                                "currency_code": "USD",
                                "value": "10.00"
                            },
                            "quantity": "1",
                            "name": "Item 2",
                        },
                    ],
                }]
```